# How to delete cashing by name in Javascript - pwa

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

PWA App that I'm working need to delete an entry.

Following code is used to check the cache.

```
self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Activating Service Worker ....', event);
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys()
            .then(function (keyList) {
                console.log('[Service Worker] keyList ....', keyList);
                return Promise.all(keyList.map(function (key) {
                    if (key !== CACHE_STATIC_NAME && key !== CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME) {
                        console.log('[Service Worker] Removing old cache.', key);
                        return caches.delete(key);
                    }
                }));
            })
    );
    return self.clients.claim();
});
```

I need to delete entries inside of a specific cache based on specific cache keys.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to accomplish and how that's different than the code you posted. Your current code deletes caches based on cache name (`caches.delete(key)`). Are you talking about deleting entries inside of a specific cache based on specific cache keys? Or something else?

Comment: @JeffPosnick yes,  I need to delete entries inside of a specific cache based on specific cache keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a helper function that takes in a cache name and the URL for a cache key within that named cached, and deletes the `Response` corresponding to that cache key.

```
async function deleteCacheKeyFromCache(cacheName, cacheKey) {
  const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
  await cache.delete(cacheKey);
}

// Use it like:
// await deleteCacheKeyFromCache('my-cache', '/index.html');
```

If `cacheName` doesn't exist, or `cacheKey` isn't present in `cacheName`, then the function will effectively be a no-op.

Comment: thank you, it works, can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60814757/how-to-enable-dynamic-caching-only-for-the-images-pwa question related to PWA, I'm sure you have a better answer.